# how to use Alias Name in where clause in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

firstly, I reviewed most of the answers here but I couldn't apply the solution to my case.
always it gives me an error.

I need to use the "FinalTotal" Alias name in where clause:

```
SELECT
        p.ID,
        p.TheName0, 

        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(att.S_FinalAmount),0) From tbl_groups_classes_att att 
         INNER JOIN tbl_students st 
         ON st.ID = att.StudentID
         INNER JOIN tbl_groups_classes cls
         ON cls.ID = att.ClassID

         WHERE st.ParentID = p.ID 
        and cls.TheDate BETWEEN @Date1 and @Date2 
        and att.TheStatus <> 'N'
        ) as CurrMost,

        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(att.S_FinalAmount),0) From tbl_groups_classes_att att 
         INNER JOIN tbl_students st 
         ON st.ID = att.StudentID
         INNER JOIN tbl_groups_classes cls
         ON cls.ID = att.ClassID

         WHERE st.ParentID = p.ID and cls.TheDate< @Date1 and att.TheStatus <> 'N'
        ) as PrevMost,

        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(pay.TheAmount),0) From tbl_parents_payments pay Where p.ID = pay.ParentID
        AND pay.TheDate BETWEEN @Date1 and @Date2
        ) as CurrMadf,

        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(pay.TheAmount),0) From tbl_parents_payments pay Where p.ID = pay.ParentID
        AND pay.TheDate < @Date1
        ) as PrevMadf,

        (SELECT CurrMost + PrevMost) as AllMost,
        (SELECT CurrMadf + PrevMadf) as AllMadf,
        (SELECT AllMost - AllMadf) AS FinalTotal 

        from tbl_parents p
        
        WHERE FinalTotal <> 0
```

but I got Error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'FinalTotal' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Just replace `WHERE FinalTotal <> 0` with `WHERE AllMost - AllMadf <> 0`, and `(SELECT AllMost - AllMadf)` with `AllMost - AllMadf` too ...

Comment: The finalTotal _column_ isn't available in the WHERE clause, because (logically) the WHERE clause is evaluated before the column alias is created. MySQL special trick is to use HAVING clause instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use subquery syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.TheName0, 

    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(att.S_FinalAmount),0) From tbl_groups_classes_att att 
     INNER JOIN tbl_students st 
     ON st.ID = att.StudentID
     INNER JOIN tbl_groups_classes cls
     ON cls.ID = att.ClassID

     WHERE st.ParentID = p.ID 
    and cls.TheDate BETWEEN @Date1 and @Date2 
    and att.TheStatus <> 'N'
    ) as CurrMost,

    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(att.S_FinalAmount),0) From tbl_groups_classes_att att 
     INNER JOIN tbl_students st 
     ON st.ID = att.StudentID
     INNER JOIN tbl_groups_classes cls
     ON cls.ID = att.ClassID

     WHERE st.ParentID = p.ID and cls.TheDate< @Date1 and att.TheStatus <> 'N'
    ) as PrevMost,

    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(pay.TheAmount),0) From tbl_parents_payments pay Where p.ID = pay.ParentID
    AND pay.TheDate BETWEEN @Date1 and @Date2
    ) as CurrMadf,

    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(pay.TheAmount),0) From tbl_parents_payments pay Where p.ID = pay.ParentID
    AND pay.TheDate < @Date1
    ) as PrevMadf,

    (SELECT CurrMost + PrevMost) as AllMost,
    (SELECT CurrMadf + PrevMadf) as AllMadf,
    (SELECT AllMost - AllMadf) AS FinalTotal 

    from tbl_parents p    
) as tab
 WHERE FinalTotal <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense, since there's no `GROUP BY`

But change this

```
WHERE FinalTotal <> 0
```

To this

```
HAVING FinalTotal <> 0
```

**Simplified test**

> ```
> create table test (
> id int auto_increment primary key, 
> a int, 
> b int
> );
>
> insert into test (a, b) values (1,1),(2,3);
>
> select a, b
> , a + b as ab
> , (select ab + 10) as ab10
> from test
> having ab10 > 12;
> ```

| a | b | ab | ab10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 15 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f097bdb9e38e885b3c37bcca754bdb45)*